# Identifying what this crash could be on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Usually my crash reports are straightforward and always lead to the right line number after symbolication. This one is weird though. It says the line that caused the crash was main.m, line 13, which is the line that writes `@autoreleasepool`.

Does this mean this crash happened as the app was starting up, or is it just because everything that happens in the app runs in that loop?

Also, does anyone have any idea what this crash points to? Something to do with a keyboard, and probably an international keyboard of some sort (since those are the ones I haven't really tested. Everything seems to be ok with US keyboard)

[image]

Comment: If keyboard related, it looks like the user started to dictate into the app, though I'm not sure why that would be problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean this crash happened as the app was starting up, or is it just because everything that happens in the app runs in that loop?

The former, generally. As we can see from the stack trace, a mutable array has thrown an exception upon inserting an object (`- [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]`), presumably because one attempted to insert an object at an invalid index (i. e. an index that was out of the bounds of the array).

Answer (score 0):

This means that in the crashing thread that was the last line of your code that was called. It does by far not always mean, that it is the place where the crash happened.

The top two lines in the stack trace indicate than an exception occurred. What is the exception code of the crash? Is there a `Last Exception Backtrace` in the report?

This could also be an iOS bug and your code isn't doing anything to cause it. But having the complete crash report could help understanding this.